# Delay on mobile device when performing Javascript onmousedown?

Tags: javascript

So I have this script below.

It works brilliantly on Desktop, but on Mobile there's a delay.

If you are on mobile, run the code and see it yourself.

Click on multiple times.

Is there any way to fix this on mobile?

Is there anything I'm missing in the code?

Need help.

Thanks.

```js
    var clicks = 0;
    function hello() {
        clicks += 1;
  var audio = new Audio('https://www.joiji.com/click.wav');
  audio.play();
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
```

```css
            .cat{
                background: url(https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.a5d003f6d8eae2434ac07f1b310f3f41?rik=LCY0xhBKNiUZxw&riu=http%3a%2f%2fwww.designboom.com%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2015%2f09%2fgoogle_logo_03-818x600.jpg&ehk=PtBQW0bMoGuZptNFF8o5w4Mpc5qeoLstvbWD8cr6V14%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0) no-repeat;
                cursor:pointer;
                border: none; 
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        width:100%;
        height:530px;
        max-width: 530px;
        background-size:contain;
    
}

            .cat:active{
                background: url(https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.f09202a9ba570e7f4e6e2ad4a81e76b5?rik=41OxYaWQnJlncQ&pid=ImgRaw&r=0) no-repeat;
                cursor:pointer;
                border: none; 
        width:100%;
        height:530px;
        max-width: 530px;
        background-size:contain;}
```

```html
<font size="5">clicked  <font size="7"><a id="clicks">0</a></font> times</font><br>
<button name="cat" class="cat" type="button" onmousedown="hello()"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

did the job.

Make sure to check on mobile as it may change the layout.